# Solve separation of variables problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, discrete-mathematics, mathematical-physics

Originally I had $\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}=-A e^{y/B} (\frac{dy}{dt})^2$.

Using a given hint: $\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{dx}{dt}\frac{dt}{dy}=\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}\frac{1}{x}$ and $x=\frac{dy}{dt}$

I got: $x\frac{dx}{dy}=-A e^{y/B} x^2$, separation of variables gave:

$\frac{1}{x} dx = -A e^{y/B} dy$

Where $A,B$ are constants. The initial condition is $x_0=x$. Also when solving, let $y=-\infty$ Now I'm a little stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$\frac{d(x^2)}{dy} = 2x\frac{dx}{dy}.$$

And in general form, if you have an equation $x' = f(x)g(t)$ with initial data $x(t_0) = x_0$, then the method of separation of variables writes

$$\int_{x_0}^{x(t)}\frac{du}{f(u)}=\int_{t_0}^{t}g(s)ds.$$
After that you study the existence of these integrals, find them, and try to solve the result with respect to $x(t)$.

If you have any further questions, ask in comments.

**EDIT**

Ok, let's write it down properly.

$$\int_{x_0}^{x(y)}\frac{du}{u}=-\int_{y_0}^{y}Ae^{s/B}ds,$$
$$\ln (x(y)/x_0)=-AB(e^{y/B}-e^{y_0/B}).$$
Therefore
$$  x(y)=-x_0e^{AB(e^{y/B}-e^{y_0/B})}.$$

Suppose that $B>0$ and $y_0=-\infty$. Then we can say that $x(y) =-x_0e^{AB e^{y/B}  } $.

Comment: I did try integrating each side, and I end up with 
ln$x=-ABe^{y/B}+C$, but the solution says it should be $\frac{x_0^2}{2eB}$. Ignoring the ln part, I'm stuck.

Comment: @user12279: Were you given some initial condition that you did not define?

Comment: @Amzoti I've added the initial condition, but I don't think this helps all too much.

Comment: Ok, next I believe I plug it back into the original equation? So, $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=-Ae^{y/B}x^2$. Which led to $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}\frac{1}{x_0^2}=e^{yB+ABe^{y/H}}$

Comment: EDIT to previous comment, Ok, next I believe I plug it back into the original equation? So, $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=-Ae^{y/B}x^2$. Which led to $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=e^{yB+ABe^{y/H}}x_0^2$. When $y=-\infty$, I get $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{x_0^2}{e^B}$.. but the solution says it's $\frac{x_0^2}{2eB}$ (with B not in the exponent of $e$.)

Comment: @user12279 Erm, I don't quite get how the solution of $y''_{xx} = -Ae^{y/B}x^2$ is related to the problem we are trying to solve here (namely, $xx'_y = -Ae^{y/B}x^2$).

Comment: Sorry, I did a change of variable. So the given problem is $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=-Ae^{y/B}x^2$, since $\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}\frac{1}{x}$, I substituted that into the given problem to get what I posted initially.

Comment: @user12279 My intuition says that the equation $\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}\frac{1}{x}$ is not correct. Could you provide your reasoning behind it?

Comment: $\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{dx}{dt}\frac{dt}{dy}=\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}\frac{1}{x}$ I was given this as a hint along with my problem

Comment: @user12279 when did $t$ come into play? These relations seem completely arbitrary to me. Maybe, it's better to post the initial problem with all hints and with all provided info. As it is now, this relation is not evident at all. Take $A=0$, then $x(y)$ is constant (since $xx'_y=0$), therefore $y'_x$ is not even defined.

Comment: I've added the rest of the problem, my apologies.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are on the right track. Starting with
$$ \frac{1}{x} dx = -A e^{y/B} dy $$ you have the equation separated. Now you can integrate each side to get
$$ \ln(x)=-ABe^{y/B} + C,  $$ where $C$ is an integration constant to be determined with the boundary condition, e.g. $y(x=0)=y_{0}$. With some algebra you can write the solution for $y$ explicitly as
$$ y(x) = B \cdot \ln[\frac{\ln(x)+C}{-AB}].$$

Hope this helps some,

Paul Safier

Or, if you want the equation written explicitly in $x$ with the boundary condition of $x(y=0)=x_{0}$ you'll find that $C=\ln(x_{0})+AB$, and thus,
$$ x(y)=\exp[C-ABe^{y/B}],$$ where 
$$C=\ln(x_{0})+AB.$$

Cheers,

Paul Safier